# Mysql select query using php

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am trying to  fetch all the rows from table 'student'.
But it returns only first row in an array.
How can I fetch all the rows in an array?

my code is-

```
<?php
  // con ref
  $dbCon = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("connection problem".mysql_error());
  // db con
  mysql_select_db("mysql_db",$dbCon);
  $sql = "select * from student ";
  $data = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
  print_r($row);
?>
```

Comment: google is your friend. "fetch all the rows in an array" = many results: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=fetch%20all%20the%20rows%20in%20an%20array&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=d76eed8efe782f95&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.aWM&biw=1680&bih=903

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) or [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs on [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Note **a** result.

You will want to loop through all rows, something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
   // Use $row here..
}
```

Also, you should note that the use of `mysql_*` functions is **deprecated**. See the big red box [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the results.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($data) ) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

An example how to iterate over a result.

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php

Comment: Please do not encourage a noobie in the evils of PHP MYSqL- library

Answer (score 0):

Number one stop using msql_ it is deprecated.
Number two read the man- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

It clearly states that the function `mysql_fetch_array` returns a row